# jQuery clone row in editable table

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a couple of issue in my Editable Table.

I am cloning both the row, but the cloned rows are not editable as the original ones. I need them editable to calculate the Total amount.

How can I clone my table row in order to keep them editable as?

The second issue, I am struggling to put the remove button as in this example<sup>(link broken)</sup> instead of the add button in any row cloned. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would need to call again the .editable() initialization method after you inserted new rows in order for the plug-in to include those rows. Put the method call into a function and call this function on document ready and after you added a row. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WKaR9/4

Comment: Thanks, the rows are now editable but are not included in the total amount because they dont pick it up the function, Trying out what you are saying with no results. This is a call back i made previously in order to calculate the amount in any input text number: callback: function() {
        tally('p#subtotal');
        tally('p#total');